# Image rendered differently for each eye (UE4 + VXGI + VR)

Tags: unreal-engine4, voxel, virtual-reality

Project: 
I have a scene in Unreal Engine which is using VXGI for the global illumination of the space. The scene is well optimized and I have good FPS (>90fps). The scene includes a movable direct light (sun) which is making the transition day-night and this is the only light source in the scene. The game has to run on HTC Vive.

Problem:
If I run the scene as a standalone app, I have the correct reflections and shadows.  If I run in VR, I can see the correct image in the left eye, while in the right I cannot see any shadows and everything in the scene is over-lit.

Solution that I've found but not suitable in my case:
- If I make the sun stationary, I see the correct image in VR
- If I uncheck the VXGI indirect lighting for the sun (and keep the VXGI on in the post-processing volume), I get the correct image for both eyes

Question: Is there any way to get the dynamic sun to work with VXGI and have a decent image in VR? (even if the framerate will drop a bit...)

P.S. This is a research project for Lighting Design and the VXGI is a must as well as the VR.

Thank you.